# Handle one account with NewMailEx where there are multiple accounts

Tags: vba, outlook

In MS Outlook there are two accounts. For most incoming email the two accounts receive the same email, sometimes in CC or TO fields together. The two accounts are similar and have almost the same subfolders.

Application_NewMailEX triggers twice if email is sent to both accounts.

I need to handle only one account (Inbox folder and its subfolders) and not the second one.

**My purpose is execute the code in the NewMailEx sub only one time and only for one of the two email accounts set up in Outlook and not for the other one.**

The code after some jobs inserts some values in a SQL Server DB.

Something like:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim arr()       As String
    Dim NS          As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim itm         As MailItem
    Dim m           As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i           as Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    arr = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Set itm = NS.GetItemFromID(arr(i))        
        If itm.Class = olMail Then
            Set m = itm               
            ' Filter 
            If m.Sender = "Our Client" and Trim(m.Subject) = "12 AXR check" then            
                ' operations
                '....           
                ' Insert DB
                '....
            End If        
            ' Other things
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Please post the code you have and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Post your code so we can help you

Comment: Thanks Miqi. I've posted a piece of code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding why there is duplication I can suggest you verify the inbox first.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

Dim arr() As String
Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace

'Dim itm As Mailitem
Dim itm As Object               ' <---

Dim m As Outlook.mailitem
Dim i As Integer

'On Error Resume Next
' If you need this determine the exact place then
'  turn error bypass off as soon as possible with
'On Error GoTo 0

Set NS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

arr = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(arr)

    Set itm = NS.GetItemFromID(arr(i))

    If itm.Class = olMail Then

        Set m = itm

        Debug.Print "mail received"
        Debug.Print itm.Parent.Parent.name

        If itm.Parent.Parent.name = "someone@somewhere.com" Then
            ' operations
            Debug.Print " item in my inbox processed"

        Else
            Debug.Print " item in any other inbox not processed"

        End If

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Niton, I'll try tomorrow and I let you know the result. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I only made a small change and its working

```
If InStr(1, LCase(itm.Parent.Parent.FolderPath), "sharingaccount@123.abc") > 0 Then
   Debug.Print "OK"
End If
```

I used that code because I have a structure, for the accounts, like the following and I wanted to handle only and exclusively incoming email in `SharingAccount` and its `subfolder`:

```
MyPersonalMail@123.abc
   Inbox
      Documents
      FromLinux
      FromAra

SharingAccount@123.abc
   Inbox
      Documents
      FromLinux
      FromAra
```

Thanks