Convert email attachment from HTML to XLSX
I have a shared mailbox that daily receives emails with an Excel attachment.
I have a power query to read the Excel file contents from each attachment in that inbox. It is failing because

Extension is not as expected.

I believe this is due to the Excel attachments have ".XLS" in the attachment name and so the file name reads M12345.XLS.XLS
Is there VBA code or a function that removes the .XLS from the file name every time an email is received?
Free Power Automate doesn't allow Excel conversions.
(In the meantime I asked the sender to check the naming convention and remove .xls from the filename.)
Correction: The file is in html format. I am looking to convert the file to xlsx.

Do you need to remove the additional .XLS in the file name or coverte the file to e.g. XLSX?

Are you certain the attachments are actual xls files?  Occasionally I see files with xls extensions which are actually in HTML format (because Excel will open these without complaining).  This is still the case for many "Excel" files produced by reporting apps or downloaded from websites.

Methods for extracting the extension from a filename all typically just find the last period in the filename and fetch the content to the right of that: having another period in the filename is not a problem, since there are no rules against that.

Tim, you are correct it is in HTML file attachment.  excel does allow me to open it after a few messages.    Shrotter, ideally i need the file in XLSX format .  the .XLS in the filename isnt essential, so long as it allows the file to be recognised as xlsx.

@Ryan, thank you. do i need to be in the specific outlook folder before i paste this in the vba editor?  as i only want the rule to apply for a certain shared inbox and a sub folder within it, not all my mailboxes.   for example. mailbox is 'sharedmailbox@email.com'  and the subfolder is 'mastercardemails'

It's best to post comments asking about an answer directly below that answer, nit under your question.  In any case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746997/478884 shows how to handle "new mail" events for a specific mailbox only.  You'd need to (1) Export the attachment to disk (2) Open the exported file in Excel and save as a "real" xlsx-format version (3) [not sure what you'd do here since we don't have much detail on your exact use case]

@MarkJohnson - please check updated answer.

Maybe you can add some details about the power query setup?  Will it just run when you trigger it?  What does it do?   You could script this all from Excel VBA if that's an option.

So this should work, if you go into the VBA find ThisOutlookSession and add:
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim att As Attachment
Dim nameWithoutExtension As String
Dim itemID As Variant
Dim sharedMailbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim targetFolder As Outlook.Folder

' Set references to the shared mailbox and target subfolder
Set sharedMailbox = Session.Folders("sharedmailbox@email.com")
Set targetFolder = sharedMailbox.Folders("mastercardemails")

itemID = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
On Error Resume Next

For Each id In itemID
    Set mail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(id)
    ' Check if the email is in the target folder
    If mail.Parent = targetFolder Then
        If mail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For Each att In mail.Attachments
                ' Check if filename contains ".XLS.XLS"
                If InStr(att.FileName, ".XLS.XLS") > 0 Then
                    ' Strip the redundant extensions
                    nameWithoutExtension = att.FileName
                    Do While InStr(nameWithoutExtension, ".XLS.") > 0
                        nameWithoutExtension = Replace(nameWithoutExtension, ".XLS.", ".")
                    Loop
                    ' Final check if filename ends with redundant ".XLS"
                    If Right(nameWithoutExtension, 4) = ".XLS" Then
                        nameWithoutExtension = Left(nameWithoutExtension, Len(nameWithoutExtension) - 4) & ".XLS"
                    End If
                    ' Save the cleaned file
                    att.SaveAsFile "C:\YourFolderPath\" & nameWithoutExtension
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Obviously replace the folder path with the correct location. As for your update: correction to above. the file is in html format, so i am looking to convert the file to xlsx - no idea how you'd achieve that in VBA - I'd suggest making a separate question of how to convert HTML to XLS once you have the file on disk.
